# Upload a jpg to Dropbox in Swift using SwiftyJson

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox-api

I am stuck on how to upload a jpg image to Dropbox using the SwiftyDropbox library.
I have a number of jpg files in my iOS documents directory and though I can successfully upload text files to Dropbox, I cannot figure out how to encode the image and upload it.
For example, here is how I upload a text file where the text is stored in the variable **myText**

The text gets encoded as per the example provided in the SwiftyDropbox tutorial and uploaded as follows.

```
   let fileData = myText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
   let path = "/myFileName.txt"
   client.files.upload(path: path, mode: .Overwrite, autorename: true, body: fileData!).response { response, error in
   if let _ = response { // to enable use: if let metadata = response {
        print("OK")
   } else {
        print("Error at end")
   }
```

The problem I have having is that instead of my data being text in myText, it is a UIImage stored in **myImage**

Can anyone help me with how I can encode the jpeg to create the **fileData** so that I can upload the file?  Or am I completely off track here.

I have found examples here for an older DropBox API, but not one that I can use for SwiftyDropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
All I had to do is

```
let fileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage!, 1)
```